# Regex: Match on No Value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have created the following regex which matches either 9 consecutive numbers or 14 consecutive numbers.

```
^[0-9]{14}$|^[0-9]{9}$
```

How can I make this regex match 9 consecutive numbers or 14 consecutive numbers or null values?

Basically I want to modify the regex so that a user does not need to enter a value for this field.  Or in other words making the validation for this field optional.

Comment: What do you consider a null value? String of length 0, string of white spaces, the string `"null"`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
if (value.length && !value.match(/^(?:[0-9]{14}|[0-9]{9})$/) {
    alert('invalid value');
}
```

If string is empty, it will pass; if non-empty, it must match the regex.

Regex only solution:

```
if (!value.match(/^(?:[0-9]{14}|[0-9]{9})?$/) {
    alert('invalid value');
}
```

Comment: I wanted to keep this purely in the regex.

Comment: Excellent!  Thanks for updating.  One follow up, is it necessary to use the ?: part to group the tokens?  Just asking for my own understanding.

Comment: @kmb385 the ?: is to prevent the regex engine to treat it as a memorized group. The speed gain is probably negligible, but it's good to be exact :)

Answer (score 1):

Just add another alternative.

```
^[0-9]{14}$|^[0-9]{9}$|^$
```

You could refactor it to optional 9 followed by another optional 5 digits, too.

```
^([0-9]{9}([0-9]{5})?)?$
```

If you don't need capturing groups, non-capturing groups with `(?:...)` will be slightly faster, but in this context, the difference is negligible.